# Using master detail pages for windows universal apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, master-detail

I want to make windows universal app using master detail pages. It should look like [image: this]

I found a lot of information about master detail, but almost all of it is not for windows-universal app and so it doesn't work for me. So please, can you give me some links with examples of using master detail exactly on windows universal app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code example - [how to implement a responsive master/detail experience in XAML.](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail)

The Guidelines for a master/details pattern for UWP are the same of a windows phone 8.1 app. You can check details in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn997765.aspx)

Comment: I already try this, but in DataTemplate Visual Studio don't like x:DataType="viewmodels:ItemViewModel". **ItemViewModel is not supported in a Windows Universal project.**

Comment: I don't understand. Is VS showing a error when you try to build the example?

Answer (score 1):

After copying the sample in a new project, cut everything between `<Page.Resources>` and `</Page.Resources>` and wait for a minute. Then again paste the code. This is because x:Bind compiles at runtime and hence vs will need to recompile.

To run this example you might also have to delete these lines of code:

```
Style="{ThemeResource     ListBodyTextBlockStyle}" />

Style="{ThemeResource.    ListCaptionAltTextblockStyle}" />
```